# SSH Authorized_Key Login Works in One Direction Only

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh, sshd

There are three files in my setup:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
authorized_keys
```

`authorized_keys` has a copy of `id_rsa.pub` contents to allow no-password logins.

These files have been copied between two computers. If I ssh from computer1 to computer2, it works. If I ssh from coputer2 to computer1, it prompts for a password. Can someone tell me why this might happen.

Also, both systems are running Ubuntu 10.04. I have reinstalled openssh-server packages on both systems. Permissions of the files are the same. The /etc/ssh `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` files are the same. I have run with `-v -v -v` and the only difference between the two sessions, is that one says the 'key was accepted by the server', the other one just continues to the password prompt.

So what else is left to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get server debug output by stopping the server and running it from the command line:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
```

This gave me the following output, after trying to login from my other computer:

```
...
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user
...
```

Checking my directory:

```
ls -l /home/user
drwxrwxr-x 142 user user 7.7K 06-19 15:45 /home/user/
```

The correct permissions should be:

```
chmod 750 /home/user
```

After I did that, it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the fingerprint from computer1 to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on computer2?

Additionally, you should not use the same private key among many boxes, as it weakens the security should one box get cracked. Personally I use one key per client per server.

Comment: As for your second point, that's why keys should always have a password. Also see related http://superuser.com/questions/121307/is-it-reasonable-to-have-multiple-ssh-keys

Comment: The authorized_keys file is the same on both computers if that is what you mean. Also, I agree with the security issues, right now I would just like to solve the issue, even if I end up switching keys down the line.

Comment: Try setting the sshd log level to DEBUG on computer2. After a failed connection attempt, it should explain why the key was rejected.

Comment: I could not get any info on the client side using '-v -v -v'. is there another method?

Comment: Look at the logs on the server side. It is probably in `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`... Look around, you should see it. Set the sshd log level to DEBUG in `sshd_config`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check in addition to Daenyth's answer is file ownership and permissions within your ~/.ssh directory on both computers.

Make sure you are set as the user for all files in that directory: `chown *USERNAME*: ~/.ssh/*`

Also, check that the permissions are such that the the files are readable and writable by your user but not accessible by *group* or *other*: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`

Comment: yep, files and .ssh dir is owned by me, all permissions are set to 600.