# ssh Password-less login to multiple machines when you already have one

Tags: ssh, passwords

I'm a little bit confused about setting up a password-less login for multiple machines to begin with, but I think I could do it from scratch.  The problem is I already have it set up for one machine and I don't want that to be blown away when I try to set it up for the other machine.  Let's clarify:

- Machine **A**: the machine I'm connecting *from*
- Machine **B**: the machine I'm connecting *to*.  Password required
- Machine **C**: the machine I'm connecting *to*.  Password-less ssh

I have read some tutorials on setting up password-less ssh to a certain site, but they usually start with "move `id_rsa` out of the way so it doesn't get blown away," but then at the end of the tutorial it's not moved back.  If I had no help at all, here is what I would do:

1. Log into **B**
2. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/id_rsa.other`
3. `scp id_rsa.other.pub A:~/.ssh`
4. `echo "Host A \n Identity File ~/.ssh/id_rsa.other" > ~/.ssh/config`

(Note that I realize these commands may not be exactly correct, but this is just the idea).

What I'm not quite clear on is if I need to update the config for **A**, **B**, or both.  I'm fairly certain to do a password-less login from **A** to **B**, it is **A** that needs the public key .. but I also suppose I need **B** to use the correct `id_rsa` file for that public key.  Finally, I don't want the password-less login for **C** to be affected at all .. it's using `id_rsa`.  Am I going wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're connecting **A** to **B** or **A** to **C**, right? (not **A** to **B** and then **B** to **C**)

If so, then you ust need to copy your id_rsa.pub to **B** and also to **C**.

The modification of the `~/.ssh/config` file you have in step 4 in your sequence is needed if you don't use the standard `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Here's what I would do (after generating the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub)...

1. Copy id_rsa.pub (using scp, using password prompt) to B and to C
2. Log into B - `mv id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. Log into C - `mv id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The private key is kept on **A**. You can use the same private key/public key combination to connect to more than one machine.

If, for some reason, you have multiple public keys for the user on **B** or **C**, you can append them to the end of the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Yes you're exactly right .. I think this is what I need to do, but **C** is already set up properly (it already has the public key it needs I think .. can't check for sure since it doesn't allow shell access, but I can `scp` to it at least).  So I guess I really only need to do steps 1 and 2.  I'll accept if this works.

Comment: Here's the thing: the `id_rsa.pub` on **A** has a pass phrase that I don't want for **B** .. so I guess I can just generate another `id_rsa.pub` and just concatenate it.  Does `ssh-keygen` let you do that automatically, or do I have to create a new key file and concatenate manually?

Comment: The .pub is a public key file. The public key is meant to be spread around. It's really the private key on **A** that is protected by the pass phrase. You type in your pass phrase to verify that you are authorized to use the local private key. When **A** is negotiating the connection to **B** or **C**, it doesn't pass the pass phrase and, I assume, doesn't pass the private key but only receives the public key. Try running `ssh -v B` or `ssh -vv B` to see more information about the authentication negotiation.

Comment: More discussion of the pros and cons of multiple public keys in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/121307/is-it-reasonable-to-have-multiple-ssh-keys)

Comment: Just a little hint from me because this got edited three minutes ago: instead of scp the pubkey you can just run `ssh-copy-id B` and the standard pubkey will be sent to `B`. If you need you can add the parameter `-i <pubkey-file>` if you have multiple keys.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally crafted a convenient way to setup password less ssh to multiple nodes. Have been using those scripts for a while and it has been flawless for me so far. Hoping that it will help someone save time. I believe that this mechanism can run under a few minuted for a few hundred nodes at once. It is based on expect & bash scripts. Take a look at it and let me know your feedback.
Link to scripts - http://adhocshare.tk/linux/setting-password-less-ssh-across-nodes-cluster/

If you've used ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id before, the whole idea in the scripts is to automate that task on all nodes at once using pdsh and a file containing hostnames. Almost everything is automated and will save you a ton of time. Let me know how that works for you. I will be more than glad to help you.

Comment: You should post the code from there into this answer. That way if the website ever is no longer reachable, people will still be able to use the script.