# Is it a good idea to upload my private key to VPS / servers?

Tags: ssh, private-key

Saying if I am deploying my application to the server using git, and the repository needs authentication to be pulled, it will be very convenient if I just upload my private key there.

However is it a good idea to do so?

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/q/121307/820) covers some reasons for and against it.

Comment: @heavyd That's a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Convenient: Yes

Good Idea: No

In reality, if you plan on only leaving it there for an hour or so, then you could place it there, but make sure to strengthen SSH by using a separate key to authenticate (and changing the port from 22, but **not** to 2222).

A better solution would be to generate a SSH key on the VPS, then import it into the git server, that way it's not your primary key, if that server does get hacked. meaning authorization could be revoked in a very short amount of time.